# Is the "top" of a view frustum considered the top of the near plane?

Tags: javascript, opengl, math, matrix, webgl

It seems that in the following function the `top` of the frustum is considered to be at the near plane. Is this true? If not, where it the "top"?

```
/*
 * mat4.perspective
 * Generates a perspective projection matrix with the given bounds
 *
 * Params:
 * fovy - scalar, vertical field of view
 * aspect - scalar, aspect ratio. typically viewport width/height
 * near, far - scalar, near and far bounds of the frustum
 * dest - Optional, mat4 frustum matrix will be written into
 *
 * Returns:
 * dest if specified, a new mat4 otherwise
 */
mat4.perspective = function(fovy, aspect, near, far, dest) {
    var top = near*Math.tan(fovy*Math.PI / 360.0);
    var right = top*aspect;
    return mat4.frustum(-right, right, -top, top, near, far, dest);
};
```

`Math.tan(fovy*Math.PI / 360.0);` is basically `tan(fovy/2)` if `fovy` were in radians instead of degrees, so `near*tan(fovy/2)` gives the height of the top half of the near plane.

Is that what "top of the view frustum" means in OpenGL, or is that just specific to this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current versions of OpenGL do not really have the concept of a frustum in the API. There are just vertex shaders that produce clip coordinates. How they do that, including what transformations they apply, is completely up to the caller. Of course it's still common to use projection matrices that are defined as view frustums.

For the `glFrustum()` call in legacy OpenGL, your observation is absolutely correct. `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `top` are measured at the `near` plane. From the [man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml):

> Typically, the matrix mode is GL_PROJECTION, and left bottom - nearVal and right top - nearVal specify the points on the near clipping plane that are mapped to the lower left and upper right corners of the window, [..]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was noticing in lesson 1 of learningwebgl.com. But learningwebgl.com doesn't explain anything about how the matrices work. It just shows you how to use the functions. I wonder if there's a nicer set of lessons/tutorials that teach you from the ground up all the theory.